# How to create and integrate custom qr code in flutter

Tags: flutter, qr-code, react-qr-code, flutter-qrcode

I want to add a qr code for my application. How can I integrate and scan the QR code I will generate? I would be very grateful if you could give me some explanatory information about the methods I will use and how to do it.

Will qr_code_scanner work for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use packages: 
qr-code generator: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter 
qr-code scanner: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

Everything will work fine if you read the documentation and follow it.